# Length of each list object - Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a list:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add(23.23);
list.add(234);
list.add("abcd");
```

I am iterating it like:

```
for(Object o : list){
    // System.out.println(o.getClass());
    if(o.getClass().equals(Integer.class)){

    }
    else if(o.getClass().equals(Double.class)){

    }
    else if(o.getClass().equals(String.class)){

    }
}
```

How to get the length of each object?

**Expected output:**

```
4
3
4
```

Comment: Depending on its type (`String` has a ready method, for `int` you'll have to do something else). Also in the first example I guess you want to get 5 not 4.

Comment: what do you mean by the length of each object?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't demonstrate minimal understanding of the problem being solved.

Comment: You could convert every item to String and get the length. `23.23` is length of 5. Are we to exclude decimals?

Comment: @MarounMaroun I love those vintage SO close reasons :D

Answer (score 3):

If *primitives* like integer, double are passed, they are *auto-boxed* to their wrappers like `Integer, Double`. And they don't have *length* attribute. Yes `String` has length attribute and a method with the same name.

So,

> 1. Use *Generics* .
> 2. If you want to find length of *int / double*, convert them to a String using `String.valueOf()` and then call `length()`.

Comment: Yes.. Using generics is a very good advice.

Comment: @MarounMaroun - Indeed it is :)

Answer (score 0):

As TheLostMind said :

```
for(Object o : list){
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(o).length());
}
```